# How to write to Cassandra using foreachBatch() in Java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code and i would like to write into cassandra using spark 2.4 structured streaming **foreachBatch**

```html
        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "topic1")
                .load();

        Dataset<Row> values=df.selectExpr(
                "split(value,',')[0] as field1",
                "split(value,',')[1] as field2",
                "split(value,',')[2] as field3",
                "split(value,',')[3] as field4",
                "split(value,',')[4] as field5");

//TODO write into cassandra 

values.writeStream().foreachBatch(
                    new VoidFunction2<Dataset<String>, Long> {
                public void call(Dataset<String> dataset, Long batchId) {

                    // Transform and write batchDF
       
            }
            ).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.forEachBatch`, your code is just working as with normal datasets... In Java the code could look like as following (full source is [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/streaming/StructuredStreaming.java)):

```java
.foreachBatch((VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>) (df, batchId) ->
         df.write()
         .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
         .options(ImmutableMap.of("table", "sttest", "keyspace", "test"))
         .mode(SaveMode.Append)
         .save()
)
```

Update in September 2020th: support for spark structured streaming was added in the [Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex.

Answer (score -1):

Try add it to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

after that import cassandra implicits:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
```

than you can use cassandraFormat method on your df:

```
dataset
      .write
      .cassandraFormat("table","keyspace")
      .save()
```